# inefficient code: comparing combining different columns from different files awk or perl?

Tags: python, perl, bash, awk

I have two files and I would like to match column 2 from file1 with column NF from file2. If they match I would like to output the whole line from file2 with, with in addition column 5 from file1  and column 5 from file 1 multiplied with column NF-2 from file 2at the end. The files have different lenghts.

I have the following two file-types:

file1

```
xx  name1 1 we    freq1
xy  name2 2 wer   freq2
xz  name3 3 werf  freq3
```

file2

```
..... value1 cv name1
..... value4 cvb name4
..... value3 cvb name3  
..... value1 vbn name5
```

desired output

```
..... value1 cv name1 freq1 (freq1*value1)
..... value3 cvb name3 freq3 (freq3*value3)
```

I have tried doing this using awk.

> awk 'FNR==NR { two[$0]++; next } { for (i in two) { split(i, one); if
>   (one[2] == $NF) print $0, one[5], $(NF-2)*one[5] } }' file1 file2 >
>   file3

It works, but is super inefficient, and makes my comp crash after a while. 
The files are about 100,000 lines each. Maybe I should use perl or python for this? Or is there a way to read file 2 as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the best way is to read *all* of the relevant columns (2 and 5) from `file1` into a hash, and then just process `file2` line by line.

If the hash uses `file1` column 2 as a key, then it can simply be indexed with the value of the last column of `file2` to see if there was a corresponding value in the other file.

Then all that is necessary is to print the values from the `file2` record, plus the calculated values using the data from the hash element.

This program demonstrates. The variable names are a little obscure as you don't give a meaning to the fields in your question, so all I can do is refer to file and column numbers.

I have had to output `string*string` instead of the actual product, because your data doesn't have numerical values.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh1, '<', 'file1';
my %file1;
while (<$fh1>) {
  my ($f1_2, $f1_5) = (split)[1,4];
  $file1{$f1_2} = $f1_5;
}

open my $fh2, '<', 'file2';
while (<$fh2>) {
  my @f2_rec = split;
  my ($f2_nm2, $f2_n) = @f2_rec[-3,-1];
  if (my $f1_5 = $file1{$f2_n}) {
    print join(' ', @f2_rec, $f1_5, "$f1_5*$f2_nm2"), "\n";
  }
}
```

**output**

```
..... value1 cv name1 freq1 freq1*value1
..... value3 cvb name3 freq3 freq3*value3
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need is:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$NF;next} $NF in a{print $0, a[$NF], a[$NF] * $(NF-2)}' file1 file2
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file1
xx  name1 1 we    3
xy  name2 2 wer   5
xz  name3 3 werf  7

$ cat file2
..... 2 cv name1
..... 4 cvb name4
..... 6 cvb name3
..... 8 vbn name5

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$NF;next} $NF in a{print $0, a[$NF], a[$NF] * $(NF-2)}' file1 file2
..... 2 cv name1 3 6
..... 6 cvb name3 7 42
```

Comment: +1 It is just amazing how short and concise the awk answer is compared to the other ones

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ane'
  BEGIN{ open($f,shift)||die$!; %h = (%h, (split)[1,4]) while <$f> }
  $fq = $h{$F[-1]} or next;
  s|$| sprintf(" %s (%s)", $fq, "$fq*$F[-3]") |e;
  print;
' file1 file2 > file3
```

Expressed as a standalone script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my %frequencies;

my $frequency_file = shift @ARGV;
open my $fh, "<", $frequence_file or die "Can't open $frequency_file: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
  my (undef, $name, undef, undef, $freq) = split;
  $frequencies{$name} = $freq;
}

while (<>) {
  my @fields = split;
  my ($value, $name) = @fields[-3, -1];
  next if not exists $frequencies{$name};
  my $freq = $frequencies{$name};
  print join(" ", @fields, $freq, "($freq * $value)"), "\n";
}
```

output

```
..... value1 cv name1 freq1 (freq1*value1)
..... value3 cvb name3   freq3 (freq3*value3)
```

Remove double qoutes for `"$fq*$F[-3]"` to do actual multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works much faster than my awk program, but Borodin's answer is even faster.

Comment: @madieke can you tell how much is faster?